# SQL Login Properties - User Mapping

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

Of course I can use SMS to check the box below... but how would I do it with a script or from SQLCMD?

[image: Screen shot from SMS]

Answer (score 1):

To create a login:

```
CREATE LOGIN login_name
WITH PASSWORD = 'yourpassword';
```

To link a user to login:

```
USE YourDatabaseHere;
CREATE USER your_user FOR LOGIN [login_name];
```

If you want, to read the exact script by your SMS, you can check the DB and then click on Script link (upper of your window) and show the script.

Comment: What if the user already exists and I just want to map the user to a Database?  I also need to check the box for Database Role Membership.  Thanks

Comment: Try this: ALTER USER your_user WITH LOGIN = login_name

Comment: I am also getting it mapped to the 'master' database instead of the one I want.

Comment: Every database has its users. An user in local to database. So you must create another on your db.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found the solution:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [Domain\Groupname] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
CREATE USER [Domain\Groupname] FOR LOGIN [Domain\Groupname]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'Domain\Groupname';
GO
```